# OpenGL ES - Repeating same texture over different vertices

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, textures

Suppose I have a polygon ( a lengthy rectangle ) made up of several triangles using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

[image]

Now imagine I have a square texture that should be mapped against each of the small square that make up the rectangle. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Start here!!!!  http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html  I have always stuck with emulated gl quads in opengl es.  It does mean more points, but it works!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat your texture along the geometry. For this, you need to setup your texture's `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` to `GL_REPEAT`.

Then you can assign texture coordinates for your vertices :

- (0,0), (0,1) for the 2 vertices on the first column
- (1,0), (1,1) for the 2 vertices on the 2nd column
- (2,0), (2,1) for 3rd column
- and so on

Comment: i am new to opengl...can you please provide some code or example...i want same